# Как выделить цветом ячейки в которых встречаются две заглавные буквы [A-Z]?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

У меня есть листы в Excel в котором часть ячеек содержит пары заглавных букв [A-Z]. Мне нужно выделить все эти ячейки цветом. Как это сделать средствами Excel?

*Ну или как включить регулярные выражения в excel?*

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @Kromster Мне нужно просто выделить цветом ячейки в которых встречаются две вподряд идущие заглавные буквы. Это очень простая регулярка, но в этом экселе их просто нету.

Comment: Поправил вопрос, проверьте.

Answer (score 8):

Добавьте условное форматирование по формуле: `=СОВПАД(A1;ПРОПИСН(ЛЕВСИМВ(A1;2)))` т.е. форматировать те ячейки которые содержат 2 символа и оба строчные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Изменил немного формулу, добавил условие, что длина строки равна 2, т.к. первое условие срабатывало и для одной заглавной буквы.

`=И(СОВПАД(A1;ПРОПИСН(ЛЕВСИМВ(A1;2)));ДЛСТР(A1)=2)`

Comment: А как английские A-Z выделять? Использвать функции на английском? И можно ли сделать поиск по всем символам, а не только по первым двум (я так понял 2  это второй символ в ячейке)?

Comment: Приведенное форматирование, выделит и латинские буквы и русские, если надо выделять только 2 заглавные латинские буквы, то подойдет что-то типа: `=И(КОДСИМВ(ПСТР(A1;1;1))>=КОДСИМВ("A");КОДСИМВ(ПСТР(A1;1;1))<=КОДСИМВ("Z");КОДСИМВ(ПСТР(A1;2;1))>=КОДСИМВ("A");КОДСИМВ(ПСТР(A1;2;1))<=КОДСИМВ("Z");ДЛСТР(A1)=2)` но все это только по первым 2 символам, поиск по всей строке скорее всего не получится, это не регулярное выражение

Answer (score 0):

[Как включить и использовать регулярные выражения в Excel](http://vremya-ne-zhdet.ru/zametki-po-vb-i-vba/vba-excel/regulyarnyye-vyrazheniya/)

Получился такой макрос:

```
Sub fillCell()
    Dim oWkb As Workbook
    Set oWkb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim oWsh As Worksheet

    Dim SheetsArray
    SheetsArray = Array(1) ' Array("Лист1")

    Dim Cell As Object

    Dim RegExpAZ As New RegExp
    With RegExpAZ
        .pattern = "[А-Я,A-Z]{2}"
    End With

    ' Можно перебирать все листы книги `oWkb.Worksheets`, либо задать их номера или названия в массиве `SheetsArray` (в данном варианте участвует только первый лист)
    For Each Sheet In SheetsArray ' oWkb.Worksheets
        Set oWsh = oWkb.Worksheets.Item(Sheet) ' Sheet

        ' Указываем диапазон:
        ' Количество строк (либо все строки на странице `oWsh.Rows.Count`)
        For r = 1 To 16 ' oWsh.Rows.Count
            ' Количество столбцов (либо все столбцы на странице `oWsh.Columns.Count`)
            For c = 1 To 8 ' oWsh.Columns.Count
                Set Cell = oWsh.Cells(r, c)
                ' Ищем совпадения по регулярному выражению
                If (Cell <> "") And (RegExpAZ.Test(Cell)) Then
                    ' Выделяем цветом ячейку, соответствующую условию
                    With Cell.Interior
                        .pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 5296274
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    Next
End Sub
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вариант для проверки двух первых символов:

```
=И(СОВПАД(ПСТР(A1;{1;2};1);ПРОПИСН(ПСТР(A1;{1;2};1))))
```

> *Khipster*: А как английские A-Z выделять?... можно ли сделать поиск по всем символам, а не только по первым двум?
>
> *Zufir*: Без VBA - видимо, никак.

Не обижайте Excel :)
Хоть на листе и проблематично работать с регулярками, но и без них можно.

Формула условного форматирования:

```
=СЧЁТ(1/(НАЙТИ(ПСТР(A1&ПОВТОР(" ";20);СТРОКА($1:$19);1);"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")*НАЙТИ(ПСТР(A1&ПОВТОР(" ";20);СТРОКА($2:$20);1);"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")))
```

Не нужно бояться, тут все сравнительно просто.

В формуле два фрагмента, одинаковых по логике работы:

```
ПСТР(A2&ПОВТОР(" ";20);СТРОКА($1:$19);1)

ПСТР(A2&ПОВТОР(" ";20);СТРОКА($2:$20);1)
```

Отличие второй *ПСТР* - из строки последовательно извлекаются символы, начиная со второго. Т.е. в паре две функции проверяют два соседних символа.

Берем последовательно  каждый символ текста. За это отвечает функция *СТРОКА()*

Чтобы не определять длину текста, добавляем символы: *ПОВТОР(" ";20)*

Объединяем по *И* два значения (здесь правильнее писать - условия):

```
НАЙТИ(символ1;перечень_символов)*НАЙТИ(символ2;перечень_символов)
```

*ИСТИНА* (число), если два символа подряд найдены в перечне символов. При других результатах - ошибка (одна или две функции *НАЙТИ* покажут ошибку *#ЗНАЧ!*)

Итог работы этой части - массив значений и ошибок, например *{#ЗНАЧ!:72:#ЗНАЧ!:#ЗНАЧ!}*

```
=СЧЕТ(1/полученный_массив)
```

Функция игнорирует ошибки, считает только значения - количество пар заглавных букв. Если формула на листе, нужно добавить условие: *=СЧЕТ(...)>0.

Нужно отметить, что в текстах "TEstER" и "TESter" функция определит по две пары.

Условное форматирование (УФ) само понимает, что любое число, отличное от нуля, *ИСТИНА*, поэтому формулу в УФ с нулем можно не сравнивать.

Answer (score -2):

Без VBA - видимо, никак. В Excel нет регулярок на уровне листов, если ничего не изменилось в самых последних версиях.
С VBA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops